# Embedding Equinox 3.2.1 into WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere, osgi, equinox

I am trying to embed an **Equinox** framework over a **Websphere 6.1** server but after trying almost everything I think I need some help.

The main problem seems to be that I cannot import any framework that I want on my project (newer Equinox, Apache Felix, etc.). When I do I get lots of exceptions that tell me that the class loaded are not the ones that I want (ClassNotFoundException, MethodNotFoundException, etc).

So I found out that I need to use a certain version (**org.eclipse.osgi_3.2.1.R32x_v20060919.jar**) which comes with Websphere. The problem: I don't know how to get a **BundleContext**.

Things I've tried:

1. Using `ServiceLoader` class:

   ```
   FrameworkFactory ff = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class);
   ```

   *Result*: I need to use Java 1.5 which doesn't have the ServiceLoader class.
2. Using `EclipseStarter` class to start a framework:

   ```
   BundleContext context = EclipseStarter.startup(new String[]{},null);
   ```

   *Result*: Throws an exception telling that Eclipse is already running.
3. Using `EclipseStarter` to get the system bundle context:

   ```
   BundleContext context = EclipseStarter.getSystemBundleContext();
   ```

   *Result*: The method is not implemented on this version.
4. Using the `EquinoxFactory` class:

   ```
   Framework fw = new EquinoxFactory().newFramework(...);
   ```

   *Result*: My version of Equinox doesn't have the EquinoxFactory class implementation.

I don't know what else to try. I cannot find much documentation about this version and almost everything I find is about using the console, not embedding the framework.

If I get this right, we will avoid having to launch a new JVM just for creating a PDF (we are trying to use multiple versions of Apache FOP)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 6.1, WebSphere itself runs on Equinox. Your description of the problem indicates that your code is actually not attempting to create an embedded Equinox container, but instead interacts with WebSphere's Equinox container. The likely reason is that the class loaders of your application are using the default parent first delegation mode. The first thing you need to do is to configure them to use parent-last mode, so that your application becomes isolated from the Equinox code in WebSphere. This will also remove the constraint on the type and version of the OSGi container that you can use.

Comment: It is very possible that what you say can solve the issue. The problem is that it is not possible to change that behavior since the results can be unpredicted for other sections of the application.  
A silly question: Since WebSphere runs on Equinox (I suppose it's a Bundle itself) is there a possibility to load my custom bundles alongside and use them from, let's say a servlet?.

Comment: In theory that is possible, but I would strongly recommend NOT to do that. Messing with the server runtime to solve an issue in an application is not a good idea, and if you have WebSphere administrators/engineers/architects who take their job serious, they will not allow you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you can move up to WebSphere 7 you could install the [OSGi Applications Feature Pack](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/osgi/). This would allow you to take advantage of the Enterprise OSGi programming model; for example, you could use Blueprint to inject a bundle context, or you could go further and use Blueprint to declaratively do many of the things you'd normally do with a bundle context anyway. If you can go to WebSphere 8.5.5 Liberty Profile, you can install arbitrary bundles into the server itself as extensions ([user features](https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/docs/article_creatingfeatures/), as well as installing OSGi Applications. However, both of those solutions require infrastructure upgrades, which it doesn't sound like you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use ServiceLoader then you can just directly instantiate the Equinox implementation of `FrameworkFactory`, which is `org.eclipse.osgi.launch.EquinoxFactory` (as indicated by reading the `META-INF/services` entry of the Equinox JAR).

For more information on embedding OSGi, see a blog post I wrote a while ago: http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html

Comment: I also remember trying that option but the jar doesn't even have the `FrameworkFactory` class.

Comment: ...adding your suggestion to the list of attempts (number 4)

Comment: Oh you're using Equinox 3.2??? You know that's around 9 years old, right? You need to use at least something like version 3.5 for OSGi Release 4.2 support.

Comment: I also notice that you state in your question "I need to use a certain version (3.2) which comes with Websphere". Why is that? It's not a technical limitation... so is your manager or customer telling you that you have to use this 9-year-old version??

Comment: If it was only that... XD. We use Apache FOP 0.20.5 for most reports, no DB persistance layer, thanks God we use Struts for some applications (others use no framework at all), etc, etc. It is very difficult to change something here and we have to make do with what we've got.

Comment: Ah, so the pain is self-inflicted. In that case I can't help.

Comment: Thanks anyway for trying. Anyhow it seems that the problem is caused by what Andreas Veithen mentioned. The OSGI classes being loaded are the ones from WebSphere itself and that's why compiling the project with any other version causes NoSuchMethodError to be thrown.